# Select multiple columns from flex column chart?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5, flash-builder4.5

Is it possible to select multiple columns from column chart in flex. Im trying to select multiple columns and grab respective data .Is it possible ... any ideas ?

Comment: Flex charts (both MX and our chart library : http://www.flexicious.com/Home/Dashboard ) have the itemClick event. This event contains information about the item the user clicked on.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Actually i am trying to select multiple columns from bar chart or column chart. according to selected columns in my app another chart will populate. User is capable of select or deselect column from column chart or bar chart. when user click on single bar on column or bar chart .. bar will select and he/she can select another column.if user wants deselect selected column he/she can again click on selected bar.